# Bootstrap Mobile Responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I am attempting to create a website that is mobile responsive within the Bootstrap CSS.

However, the buttons are non responsive (as in they do not resize) when I attempt to resize the page.

This is the CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px) {
    #button1, #dropdown1, #dropdownMenu1 {
        width: 50px;
        text-align: left;
    }
}

#button1, #dropdown1, #dropdownMenu1 {
    width: 120px;
    text-align: left;
}

#button2, #dropdown2, #dropdownMenu2 {
    min-width: 120px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d41jx7gm/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is OK in your code. just write the media query at the end of the CSS.

the changed code looks like this.

> ```
> #button1, #dropdown1, #dropdownMenu1 {
>     width: 120px;
>     text-align: left;
> }
> #button2, #dropdown2, #dropdownMenu2 {
>     min-width: 120px;
>     text-align: left;
> }
> .caret {
>     float: right;
>     position: relative;
>     top: 8px;
> }
> @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px) {
>     #button1, #dropdown1, #dropdownMenu1 {
>         width: 50px;
>         text-align: left;
>     }
> }
> ```

Here is the working [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pranayjoshicse/g0taf4xp/)

Comment: Thank you very much.  Works perfectly.